# Backpack 4.1 Routes syntax

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm updating Laravel 5.4 to Laravel 8, so far everything goes "well" it's time consuming but the upgrade worth it.

My problem is that I don't know Backpack very well and the upgrade is considerable.

I'm now stuck with the new route syntax, there where a `CRUD::resource` facade that handled route customization  that is not available anymore.

What would be the right approach for the following "simplified" custom route files. (I removed everything I figured already)

```
Route::group([
        'prefix'     => config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin'),
        'middleware' => [
            'web',
            config('backpack.base.middleware_key', 'admin'),
        ],
        'namespace'  => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin',
    ], function() { // custom admin routes

        Route::get('report', function() {
            $clients  = ClientWithSubscription::get();
            $clientsT = transformer()->transform($clients);
            return view('clients')->withClients($clientsT['data']);
        });

        // Client
        CRUD::resource('client', 'ClientCrudController');
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'client/{client_id}'], function() {
            CRUD::resource('address', 'ClientAddressCrudController');
            CRUD::resource('subscription', 'ClientSubscriptionCrudController');
        });

        // Taxonomy
        foreach (['theme', 'tag', 'subject', 'utility', 'document_type', 'special_need', 'level', 'platform', 'other', 'shop',] as $taxonomy) {
            CRUD::resource('taxonomy/' . $taxonomy, 'TaxonomyCrudController');
        }

        // Items
        CRUD::resource('item/document', 'ItemDocumentCrudController');

        // Referrals
        CRUD::resource('referrals', 'ReferralCrudController')->with(function() {
            Route::post('referrals/mark-paid/{id?}', 'ReferralCrudController@markPaid');
            Route::post('referrals/mark-unpaid/{id?}', 'ReferralCrudController@markUnpaid');
            Route::post('referrals/edit-notes/{id}', 'ReferralCrudController@editNotes');
        });
});
```

My questions are

- How do I add a prefix to all crud route ?
- If a CrudController use default route, then it mean I don't need to declare it at all, Backpack will take care of it ?
- How do I add custom method to the CRUD Route ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two changes are needed:

- instead of `CRUD::resource('item/document', 'ItemDocumentCrudController');` you should now do `Route::crud('item/document', 'ItemDocumentCrudController');`
- the extra routes inside the `->with()` closures should be moved after the appropriate `Route::crud()` statement;

See [this step in the Backpack upgrade process](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/upgrade-guide#routes-1) for more details.

Also, make sure to upgrade to Backpack 4.0 (using its upgrade guide), and only after it's working to upgrade to Backpack 4.1 (the latest version).